# Slow query performance on Oracle 19c depending on date

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

A few weeks ago we upgraded an Oracle database to 19c and everything was working ok.

Last week, query performance degraded one evening and we don't really know why.

Why would Oracle Optimizer return they query in less than a second with dates in June and take 4 minutes to respond with dates in August. The optimizer uses a different plan for each query. We're trying to figure out what could have changed to make a query that responding quickly to one that responds so slowly in a matter of minutes.

Comment: You are going to have to provide a little more detail.  Show the table definition, indexes, the actual query, explain plans of the query.

Comment: That's not a lot of data to go on.  But it sounds like there may be an issue with the statistics particularly on the date column.

Comment: Use SQLdb360 to provide all needed details about your slow query: https://github.com/sqldb360/sqldb360